# How to remove unused CSS using webpack 4?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am having problem removing unused CSS in webpack 4. It seems that most of the CSS purification plugins are dependent on extract text plugin which is not updated for version 4.

Here's my commands:

node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode=development --env.operation=separateCSS

OR

node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode=development --env.operation=bundleCSS

Here's part of my webpack.config.js:

```
rules: [
    // Loader for SASS files
    {
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
      use: [
        // Use IIFE to choose how to emit the CSS: 1. Extract as separate file 2: Bundle with the JS file
        (() => {
          return env.operation == "separateCSS" ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader';
        })(),
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            url: true
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: [
              // Write future-proof CSS and forget old preprocessor specific syntax. 
              // Use the latest CSS syntax today with cssnext. 
              // It transforms CSS specs into more compatible CSS so you don’t need to wait for browser support.
              // It parses CSS and add vendor prefixes to CSS rules using values from Can I Use.
              // https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext
              require('postcss-cssnext')()
            ]
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "../css/[name].css"
    })
  ]
```

Does anybody know how can I modify my config file so webpack can remove unused CSS?

Comment: the best solution is stopping using unused CSS

Comment: I'm loading some internal branding CSS file similar to bootstrap. But most of the time, many parts are unused. So I need a way to omit redundant parts.

Comment: There is already a beta version for extract text plugin that works with webpack 4. Maybe thats an option if you don't find something else. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0

Comment: @Hamed were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Try the purge-css-webpack-plugin - https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-webpack-plugin - This shrunk my css files considerably and is easy to implement.

Comment: @bilcker they forked it to: https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using something called **uncss**. There's a webpack plugin for it. It will look through all your CSS and compare it to your HTML, and remove anything that you're not using.

Take a look: [WebPack UnCSS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uncss-webpack-plugin)